# Get all metadata fields from a document library in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, caml-query, .net

I've been struggling with a CAML query that will allow me to retrieve all items from a **SharePoint Online** document library and getting all the metadata as well.
I managed to get some, but not all columns, so my query is not properly structured, I guess.
I retrieve items with ID from 0 to 100, and I only get 10 of them, just because I want to fix the metadata retrieval first and then deal with everything else. Also, I only want to get files and not folders.
I only get certain metadata fields/columns, but definitely not all. For example, I want to get the contents of a field/column with internal name *Description0*.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
 private static void ExecuteListUpload()
    {
        using (var context = new ClientContext("domain.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/subsiteName/"))
        {
            var password = new SecureString();
            var plainPassword = "Password";

            foreach (var @char in plainPassword) password.AppendChar(@char);
            context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("user@domain.com", password);

            List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Document Library");

            context.Load(list);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery() ;
            query.ViewXml = @"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
                                <Query>
                                <FieldRef Name='Description0' />
                                    <Where>
                                        <And>
                                            <And>
                                                <Gt>
                                                    <FieldRef Name='ID'></FieldRef>
                                                    <Value Type='Number'>0</Value>
                                                </Gt>
                                                <Lt>
                                                    <FieldRef Name='ID'></FieldRef>
                                                    <Value Type='Number'>100</Value>
                                                </Lt>
                                            </And>
                                            <Eq>
                                                <FieldRef Name='FSObjType' />
                                                <Value Type='Integer'>0</Value>
                                            </Eq>
                                        </And>
                                    </Where>
                                    <OrderBy>
                                        <FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='True' />
                                    </OrderBy>
                                </Query>
                                <FieldRef Name='Description0' />
                                <RowLimit>10</RowLimit>
                                <ViewFields /><QueryOptions />
                              </View>";


            ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
            context.Load(items);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            Console.WriteLine(items.Count);

            foreach (ListItem item in items)
            {
                string fileInfo = String.Format(item.FieldValues["FileLeafRef"] 
                // would like to retrieve all fields here
                    );
                Console.WriteLine(fileInfo);
            }
        }
```

I also tried the following (from here https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9fb66816-0fbf-4dff-a4ca-eb962ee61084/csom-caml-query-to-get-all-listitems-with-their-fieldvalues?forum=sharepointdevelopment):

```
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("http://sp2013/sites/team");

List oList = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("CustomList45");

CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"></View>";

ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);

ctx.Load(collListItem, items => items.Include(
 item => item.Id,
 item => item.DisplayName,
 item => item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments,
 item => item.FieldValuesAsHtml,
 item => item.RoleAssignments));

ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

But I get Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: 'Value does not fall within the expected range.'
If I remove

```
item.DisplayName
```

from the query, it works fine, but I still don't get all the metadata fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the solution is bit of both code snippets, I shared, combined with proper syntax in the CAML query. In the end of the CAML query I have to include the *ViewFields* tag:

So this:

```
 <ViewFields />
```

became this:

```
<ViewFields>
   <FieldRef Name='Description0' />
</ViewFields>
```

I was confused at first, because I was left to believe, when reading some articles, that if you leave the *ViewFields* tag empty, you will get all the fields, but that was not the case, at least in my situation.
So now I can get all the fields this way - by explicitly specifying them in the query.

Here is the end code - remember, this is just a proof-of-concept kind of thing.

```
private static void ExecuteListUpload()
    {
        using (var context = new ClientContext("domain.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/subsiteName/"))
        {
            var password = new SecureString();
            var plainPassword = "Password"; 

            foreach (var @char in plainPassword) password.AppendChar(@char);
            context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("user@domain.com", password);

            List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Document Library");

            context.Load(list);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery() ;

            query.ViewXml = @"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
                                <Query>
                                    <Where>
                                        <And>
                                            <And>
                                                <Gt>
                                                    <FieldRef Name='ID'></FieldRef>
                                                    <Value Type='Number'>1</Value>
                                                </Gt>
                                                <Lt>
                                                    <FieldRef Name='ID'></FieldRef>
                                                    <Value Type='Number'>100</Value>
                                                </Lt>
                                            </And>
                                            <Eq>
                                                <FieldRef Name='FSObjType' />
                                                <Value Type='Integer'>0</Value>
                                            </Eq>
                                        </And>
                                    </Where>
                                    <OrderBy>
                                        <FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='True' />
                                    </OrderBy>
                                </Query>
                                <RowLimit>10</RowLimit>
                                <ViewFields>
                                    <FieldRef Name='Description0' />
                                </ViewFields>
                                <QueryOptions />
                              </View>";

            ListItemCollection itemsCollection = list.GetItems(query);
            context.Load(itemsCollection, items => items.Include(item => item.FieldValuesAsText));
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            Console.WriteLine(itemsCollection.Count);

            var sb = new StringBuilder();


            foreach (ListItem item in itemsCollection)
            {
                sb.Append(item.FieldValuesAsText["FileLeafRef"].ToString());
                sb.Append(" ");
                sb.Append(item.FieldValuesAsText["Description0"].ToString());

                Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());

                sb.Clear();
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
```